# Optimizing a combination of curves with constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I’m not familiar with solvers (optimization), I would like to find the optimal values for x1 and x2 that maximize a non-linear function.

```
a1 = 0.000176
b1 = 26.51410219
a2 = 0.0000403
b2 = 158.4966186
max
   fn = (b1*(1-exp(-a1*x1))+(b2*(1-exp(-a2*x2)))
Subject to
x1 + x2 <=20000
x1 <=15000
x2 >= 9000
```

If I’m to do this in excel (I would like to use R for this case) I get the following values;
fn = 152, x1 = 5695 and x2 = 14305.
I looked at quadprog packages, but I was not able get something working.
I would truly appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: your constraints are linear, you can use constrOptim by providing the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need another closing paren in that expression to be maximized. It's unclear whether you want fn or fn2:

```
fn = function(x1,x2){  (b1*(1-exp(-a1*x1))) + (b2*(1-exp(-a2*x2)))  }
fn2 = function(x1,x2){ (b1*(1-exp(-a1*x1)) + (b2*(1-exp(-a2*x2)))) }
```

One way to impose constraints is to subtract large values at the boundaries:

```
optim(par=list(10000, 10000), fn=function(x){ 
              # starting values inside constraint boundaries
          ( b1*(1-exp(-a1*x[1]))+(b2*(1-exp(-a2*x[2]))) - 
               200000*( ( x[1]+x[2])> 20000) -
               200000*(x[1]>15000) - 
               200000*(x[2] < 9000) )},
           control=list(fnscale=-1) #  to make max
       )

#---------

$par
[1]  2215.306 17784.694

$value
[1] 89.65546

$counts
function gradient 
     197       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

> 2215.306 + 17784.694
[1] 20000
```

You can see that for `fn2` the R method I suggested outperforms the Excel result:

```
> fn2( x1 = 5695 , x2 = 14305)
[1] 86.22543
> fn2(2215.306 , 17784.694)
[1] 89.65546
```

Also possible to do a graphical check on sensibility, setting the values outside the boundaries suppresses appearance in the plot:

```
vals <- outer(X=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), Y=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), FUN=function(x,y) ( b1*(1-exp(-a1*x))+(b2*(1-exp(-a2*y))) ) )
 constr1 <- outer(X=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), Y=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), FUN=function(x,y) ( x+y >20000 ) )
 constr2 <- outer(X=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), Y=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), FUN=function(x,y) ( x >15000 ) )
 constr3 <- outer(X=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), Y=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), FUN=function(x,y) ( y < 9000 ) )
 vals[constr1] <- NA
 vals[constr2] <- NA
 vals[constr3] <- NA
 persp(x=seq(5000,20000,by=1000), y=seq(5000,20000,by=1000),z=vals,ticktype="detailed", las=3,ylab="",theta=-45)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BondedDust for the help, the closing paren was missing.

Comment: So it was fn2 you were hoping for? (That was the one I used.)

Comment: In the solution above, replacing x1 and x2 with the values 2215.306, 17784.694 into fn = (b1*(1-exp(-a1*x1))) + (b2*(1-exp(-a2*x2))) give max of 136. using solver in excel I was able to get fn = 152 with  x1 = 5695 and x2 = 14305. I was hoping that R would give a better or similar results when maximizing fn. I'm I missing something here.

Comment: Sorry BondedDust, I'm after fn (not fn2), however I still got the same results when I replaced fn2 with fn in your code.

Comment: I get fn(5695,14305) = [1] 86.22543.

Comment: Sorry mate my mistake, I was replacing the values in excel in the wrong fn. R results are same as excel solver. thanks again for your help.

Comment: You mean the values of fn(.) were the same and the R parameters gave a better fit, right?

Answer (score 0):

Similar results can be achieved with constrOptim, however the constraints should have the form Ax>=b.

```
fn = function(x){
  (26.51410219*(1-exp(-0.000176*x[1]))) + (158.4966186*(1-exp(-0.0000403*x[2])))
  }
```

Rewrite the constraints as

```
 x1 +x2 <=20000 --> -x1 –x2 >= -20000
 x1 <= 15000 --> -x1 >= -15000
 x2 >= 9000
 A = matrix(c(-1,-1,-1,0,0,1),nrow=3,byrow=T)
 b = c(-20000,-15000,9000)

 constrOptim(c(5000,10000),fn,NULL,A,b,control=list(fnscale=-1))
$par
[1]  2275.632 17724.367
$value
[1] 89.65666
```